# Alternatives to Quarkus base images for native-micro

Tags: java, binary, containers, quarkus, glibc

I am building the binary in a GitHub Action pipeline using `mvnw -Pnative`. The runner machine uses the latest Ubuntu OS where the `glibc` version is 2.3x. Whereas, the base Quarkus micro image uses an earlier version of `glibc`. This results in the following error when the container image is run using `docker run`.

```bash
./application: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./application)
./application: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./application)
```

Browsing [this site](https://distrowatch.com/) for understanding the library version and distribution is tedious. Therefore, I wanted to know, if you can suggest an alternative micro base image - with "recent" `glibc` - where, a Quarkus binary can be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I couldn't reproduce this, however my host machine has newer version of `glibc` and my native container image started successfully.
Output of `ldd --version`
On the host:

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
```

On the container image (built by Dockerfile.native)

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.28
```

Both `Dockerfile.native` and `Dockerfile.native-micro` is based on UBI8 which is an **U**niversal **B**ase **I**mage of **R**ed **H**at **E**nterprise **L**inux. UBI8 is based on RHEL8 and UBI9 is on RHEL9. RHEL9 using recent `glibc 2.34`.

#### Solution #1 - use UBI9-minimal

Ubi9 minimal base image contains everything (and more), but it is a little bit bigger than `micro` version.

In this case just use this base image:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9-minimal:9.2

# ...
```

#### Solution #2 create custom micro image

[This guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/quarkus-runtime-base-image) explains how to create custom base image or extend the existing one.

This Dockerfile should work:

```
# -- Stage ubi
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9-minimal:9.2 AS ubi
# -- Stage scratch
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9-micro:9.2 AS scratch
# -- Final Stage
FROM scratch
COPY --from=ubi /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
COPY --from=ubi /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
COPY --from=ubi /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1
```

**Note**: I cloned the [quarkus-images](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images) repository and changed the arguments to generate this Dockerfile.

Comment: The suggested Dockerfile worked; thank you!